# use of serverside script in asp content file in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

it is possible,i ues **<% %>** for assign **QueryString** ID,to src "img" tag such as below code:

```
<form id="form1"  runat="server">
<div>
<img src="Default.aspx?ID=<%Request.QueryString[ID]%>/>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but it should  be like.. `<%=Request.QueryString["ID"]%>` as you forgot to add `=` and `double quote`

```
<img src="Default.aspx?ID=<%=Request.QueryString["ID"]%>/>
```